# How much coupling does product measure have?

Tags: probability

Given two probability measures on the same measurable space $\Omega$,
is their product measure the coupling with the biggest probability of $\{(x, y):  \forall x, y \in\Omega, x \neq y\}$?

If not, 
what is the coupling with the biggest probability of $\{(x, y):  \forall x, y \in\Omega, x \neq y\}$?

How is the amount of coupling  quantified  for the product measure?
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: try both marginals equal to the uniform distribution on a set of size $n$, then the largest probability of the complement of the diagonal is $1$ while it is $1-1/n$ for the product distribution.

Comment: +1 Thanks! "it is 1/n for the product distribution" or "it is 1- 1/n for the product distribution"?

Comment: It is 1-1/n. $ $